# If it's possible to combine plain and hierarchical view together?

Tags: grid, tree

I'm facing the issue of data representation. On the same page, it's possible to view both plain and tree structure. It's ok (tbh no, but we can live with it for a while), but when it comes to new object creation it feels like a duplication as it appears in two places.

1. As nested object
2. As an object in the list

**Question:**
Any idea how to solve it? How to get rid of the feeling of duplicated object? Keeping the plain and tree structure on the same page?

Thanks.

[image: short gif]

Answer (score 0):

Why not show it as a nested object only? I don't see the point of displaying it as an object in the main list as well.